# How to update Key Vault secret value without changing secret identifier?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to change a Key Vault secret value without changing secret identifier ? I tried new version button in azure portal but the secret identifier changed .

thanks , Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to control the identifier via the REST API, the .NET libraries, or the Portal, nor can the value of an existing secret version be changed. A new version always generates a new identifier. The same applies to Key Vault keys.

Comment: But when I change a value/add a new version, I have to change all referenced secret identifiers in all my applications? 
Is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: Just found this and it seems to work:
https://blog.eldert.net/reference-key-vault-secret-latest-version/

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL whitout the key:

https://kv-we-retrieve-kv-secret.vault.azure.net/secrets/MySecretValue/

Using the Secret Identifier like this, will reference the latest secret value.

Reference:
https://blog.eldert.net/reference-key-vault-secret-latest-version/

[...] However, often we will just want to reference the latest version, so we stay up to date even when the secret has been changed, for example because it is a rotating password.

It turns out, this is very easy, without the need to update the version number in all our applications whenever a new version is created. This is done by just omitting the version number from our link! So the will instead look like https://kv-we-retrieve-kv-secret.vault.azure.net/secrets/MySecretValue/.

Important to notice is the trailing slash ( / ), which needs to be included, otherwise you will just get a 404 error.[...]